# Typescript decorator type inferring issue

Tags: typescript, redux, decorator, typescript-typings

I have an issue with a TS decorator, when I want to type its function parameters.
Consider it's in a redux context. This decorator, `@OnAction`, intercepts action with its `type`.

I want that from the type I give to the decorator, this one asks for a function with the corresponding action type.
Basically, with a `@OnAction('history/modal/toggle')` I want the decorator to ask a function with a parameter `action: HistoryModalToggleAction`.

But with the following code I have a compile error on my decorator.

[Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYB4AqA+KBeKAbylEgC4pMoBfAbgFgAoJgehagGUBDAWzABsIAOmABnJkwgAPMMgBOwKIlTAIcgGZc40ABKJRweSACyyACZd+AJQhmArtrkAFOcjCiiTKFABu+xABGghQByMiCXKgMjN7IwAAWahzAdurqFAZyygDm0dQSjNKyCkoqapraUHoGRqYW-JjI2dmC8EhoUNKqqGYebSgYAOTx+oZyICw85pYshs2Cg7iEXr7+QRAhYRFRTPnMhTLyiqTQyfIQ-R0E1WMm0w1NLRcIA1AAPrAvaOiDcYlyl1QAEZFu9Pu0hn81ICAEyLaKSQ4lOD8LiiDzcPiCTz7bwAAQA8qhAQAKYajIyTe6zR4LACUKzQjXmEBJBi4qgoNi4ZjQ-BA6ButXuNnsjhcblE2AANFAtBCKELxnVLMynoC6VyIDy+QKlXd6qKHGoJe4lgVvN5EOooCSAITygZCPyiQKCBkxS3eOQQFJyVBQdmqaJeiD8UQQFZen1+gPLT1e7xCZNBiDSqOJl1ujYkOR2SMJy10FZ7XYFNhQImAkTifYnKA2TKIBC2Yy++LmdAwTpSbq9ThjZ4Q3AEEkrMCuQwnCiREDpz0AawgIAywCyqGy8+8ZggojgWTAYwomHAtlNalAABFd-vEIf5Ogx4XUzPUHOM460BQYCs6fhcLO2BMH+eC4D4yCIGYCIHMUijqHYqBfAGVZIV2PZ9hig6AtgJLTrAADagwnIMAC6moNrua7NqoZhtgknYwOauJQHAaAGFAPpNi2tHtuYWpcTRdEdmYXYjraE5xHEp6ykuc5QDue4HmMIFMRmFbJkIFo0NB3q+nY-ocZRWTcUJ5h5EwQA)

```js
// Sample.ts

export interface HistoryModalReducerProps {
  visible: boolean;
  otherStuff: string;
}

export interface HistoryModalToggleAction extends Action<'history/modal/toggle'> {
  visible: boolean;
}

export type StoreAction = HistoryModalToggleAction | Action<'otherAction1'> | Action<'otherAction2'>;

export class Sample {

  @OnAction('history/modal/toggle')
  onToggle(state: Readonly<HistoryModalReducerProps>, action: HistoryModalToggleAction): Readonly<HistoryModalReducerProps> {

    if (!action.visible)
      return state;
    else
      return {
        ...state,
        visible: true
      };
  }

}
```

```js
// OnAction.ts

type RestrictedMethod<A extends StoreAction> = (
  prototype: any,
  key: string,
  descriptor: TypedPropertyDescriptor<(
    state: any,
    action: A
  ) => any>
) => void;

export function OnAction<A extends StoreAction>(type: A['type']): RestrictedMethod<A> {

  const restrictedMethod: RestrictedMethod<A> = (prototype, key, descriptor) => {

    // ...

  };

  return restrictedMethod;
}
```

The compile error, simplified, said that in my function, `HistoryModalToggleAction` is not assignable to `StoreAction`. So my decorator waits a function with `action: StoreAction` instead of `action: HistoryModalToggleAction`. And even I close my eyes on this lack of inferrence it seems wrong, these types are compatible.

My typescript version is `3.5.3`.

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution found !

I had to change types of `OnAction` signature to narrow my action type:

```js
type NarrowAction<T, N> = T extends Action<N> ? T : never;

export function OnAction<T extends StoreAction['type']>(type: T): RestrictedMethod<NarrowAction<StoreAction, T>> {

  return (prototype, key, descriptor) => {

    // ...

  };
}
```

Now it works ! [Playground](http://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?experimentalDecorators=true#code/C4TwDgpgBAggxsAlgewHYB4AqA%20KBeKAbylEgC4pMoBfAbgFgAoJgehagGUBDAWzABsIAOmABnJkwgAPMMgBOwKIlTAIcgGZc40ABKJRweSACyyACZd%20AJQhmArtrkAFOcjCiiTKFABu%20xABGghQByMiCXKgMjN7IwAAWahzAdurqFAZyygDm0dQSjNKyCkoqapraUHoGRqYW-JjI2dmC8EhoUNKqqGYebSgYAOTx%20oZyICw85pYshs2Cg7iEXr7%20QRAhYRFRTPnMhTLyiqTQyfIQ-R0E1WMm0w1NLRcIA1AAPrAvaOiDcYlyl1QAEZFu9Pu0hn81ICAEyLaKSQ4lOD8LiiDzcPiCTz7bwAAQA8qhAQAKYajIyTe6zR4LACUKzQjXmEBJBi4qgoNi4ZjQ-BA6ButXuNnsjhcblE2AANFAtBCKELxnVLMynoC6VyIDy%20QKlXd6qKHGoJe4lgVvN5EOooCSAITygZCPyiQKCBkxS3eOQQFJyVBQdmqaJeiD8UQQFZen1%20gPLT1e7xCZNBiDSqOJl1ujYkOR2SMJy10FZ7XYFNhQImAkTifYnKA2TKIBC2Yy%20%20LmdAwTpSbq9ThjZ4Q3AEEkrMCuQwnCiREDpz0AawgIAywCyqGy8%208ZggojgWTAYwomHAtlNalAABFd-vEIf5Ogx4XUzPUHOM460BQYCs6fhcLO2BMH%20eC4D4yCIGYCKMPWAByXByK4ADugJYLKsEjpQPZ9n0XwYBhUAAPxYRQqAQD4ajQUURxQOodioHhlbEnhWDYRAPQYoOgIANqDCcgwALrYCS06UJqDa7muzaqGYbYJJ28GIcgKEsWcPqArKODmriUAxnY-q2hOcRxKespLnOUA7nuB5jCB2kZhWyZCBaNB5EwQA)